# Authenticating between Front and Back ends via Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory

Hello I currently have two azure app services running, one being my front end and the other being my backend. I would like my backend to require Microsoft authentication (AD), but whenever doing so any api calls from the front end are blocked.

How and what do I send to my backend from my front end to do this?

I am thinking of of using axios to export something to the backend whenever certain api calls are made. I am using Nodejs by the way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The flow that you should implement is the following:

- On your frontend, you authenticate your users with AAD
- During the authentication phase, you will need to acquire a proper accessToken that can be used to consume your API
- After successful authentication, you will then call your API from the frontend, passing the acquire accessToken as an Authorization header
- When the request hits the API, you will need to validate the accessToken - this is normally done by implementing a middleware component on your API that does this validation
- If the accessToken is valid, you allow the request to hit the controller logic and you return the corresponding response
- If the accessToken is not valid, you send a 401 or 403 back

For node.js, you can use passport to handle the token validation for you.

The below example uses a React app as the frontend and calls a node.js API, protected with AAD:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-tutorial/tree/main/3-Authorization-II/1-call-api